# Xbox 360 overheat/freeze, no red ring of death, x-clamp repair completed already

Tags: xbox-360, technical-issues

I have an xbox that a friend gave me with RROD issues.  I fixed it about 6 months ago by replacing the x-clamps with nuts/bolts/washers and new thermal paste.  I've been doing PC repair for years this felt like a straight forward repair.

I've been playing literally over 200 hours, it has worked great.

Starting yesterday, the game just froze - visuals stayed on screen, it just locked up, had some minor checkering artifacts, and heard a short beep.  Only solution was to turn console off/on.  This fixed it for a couple hours, then the same problem occured.  I'm playing Fallout: New Vegas so I assumed it was game bugs.

The problem quickly got worse, the console won't even run on the home screen for more than 2 or 3 minutes until it encounters this same problem.  When I turn the box off/on it resets and acts normally - no red lights, no errors; until it freezes.  I removed the ethernet and HDD, no dice.

This isn't freezing on the loading screen, it gets to the menu just fine, controller connects, I can load a game or netflix, or whatever, but it always locks up in 3-5 minutes, sometimes less.

Is there any chance of figuring out what this issue is and fixing it?  Is it the same problem that caused the RROD coming back, or a different problem?  Can someone suggest a fix?

Comment: Sounds like overheating.

Comment: I agree, but I can't figure out why or how to keep it cool.  My apartment is cool, and the xbox is on top of a shelf with a lot of room all around, well ventilated, the same place its been the entire time I've been playing it.

Comment: Did fan vibration back one of the washers off and lose thermal conductivity?  Did you use springs to ensure even tension of the heatsink?

Comment: @insta I'm not sure about loose hardware, thats a good suggestion.  I haven't opened the case again yet.  No springs.

Comment: @insta I just checked, everything is tight.

Comment: Does the fan even run?

Comment: @Virusboy yes, it starts immediately and runs continuously, even after the box locks up.

Answer (score -2):

the problem with xbox 360 is indeed overhead the only solution that works for me is strip the plastic casing the console needs way more air than its desinged do suck in as soon as you remove the plastic casing and the console has room to breath you should not have a freeze anymore a fair WARNING never touch the consoles metal when you stripped it 9 out of 10 you get a shock hope this helps